# Lambda console not opening function with :live alias by default

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

**Background**: I have set a SQS trigger in the latest lambda code. In CFN template, this property is set `AutoPublishAlias: live`

**Problem**  When I open Lambda function from the console, it doesn't show the trigger attached in UI.
However, if I navigate to SQS and open the trigger from there(using **View in Lambda** option), it opens the lambda function with `:live` alias and now i can see the trigger.

**Question**: I am confused why default lambda($LATEST) is not showing the trigger?

[image: When I open the function from functions list in lambda console]
[image: When I open the trigge from SQS console-->View in Lambda]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Triggers are not shown by default on the lambda function homepage/landing page. They show up on the `Aliases` tab. If you want to see the triggers, do the following:

1. Visit AWS Console
2. Go to Lambda Homepage
3. Search for the function and go to the function homepage
4. Below the function overview box, there are tabs. Go to Aliases tab
5. Click on the `live` alias
6. You should see your triggers on the alias.

Attached screenshots.

[image]

[image]

Comment: got it, so if i remove that property from cloudformation template, `AutoPublishAlias: live`, then since there won't be any aliases, trigger would show up for the $LATEST lambda?

Comment: Maybe, not sure. Because I think lambdas always need an alias. Even if you don't provide one, I think AWS auto assigns. Please try and let us know if you can see the triggers after removing the alias.

Comment: I was setting the alias to `live` in the deployment config. When I navigated to `live` alias from the console, it was showing up the trigger. I didn't try to remove the `live` alias but I guess, if I remove it, the trigger will show up in the default view because thats the behavior of my another lambda function.

Comment: I am curiously experiencing the inverse of this, there is an API Gateway trigger on the default view, but no triggers on the alias view even though there is an API G integration declared in terraform using the alias' invoke arn for the uri property